# Change add to cart button and text based on WooCommerce product type

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, archive

How to change a WooCommerce add to cart button in Product List loop but depending on the product type, like for example:

1. For products with Variations I want a text in add to cart button to: "Show product"
2. For Simple prodcuts "Show product"
3. For products Out of stock: "Unavailable"

I tried with below code but doesn't work:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_loop_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function replace_loop_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
    $button_text = __( "Out of stock", "woocommerce" );
    return '<a class="view-product" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';
    if( ! $product->managing_stock() && ! $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        return $button;
    }
    if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) return $button;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_loop_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function replace_loop_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
    // Out of stock products
    if( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $button_text = __( "Unavailable", "woocommerce" );
    }
    // Simple and Variable products
    elseif( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) || $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        $button_text = __( "Show product", "woocommerce" );
    } 
    // Other product types
    else {
        $button_text = add_to_cart_text(); 
    }
    
    return '<a class="view-product button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work

Comment: Yeah ! Thanks ! I only removed from there $product->managing_stock()

Answer (score 0):

To change woocommerce Book Now button I installed this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/button-customizer-for-woocommerce/ and added 2 filters to functions.php and finally, it works

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_booking_single_check_availability_text', 'wooninja_booking_check_availability_text' );
function wooninja_booking_check_availability_text() {
    return "your text";
} 
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_booking_single_add_to_cart_text', 'wooninja_woocommerce_booking_single_add_to_cart_text' );
function wooninja_woocommerce_booking_single_add_to_cart_text() {
    return "your text";
}
```

Comment: Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to improve your answers?